# .NET Core in Linux and DLLImport from foreign library

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a .NET Core project which uses `Microsoft.Xrm.Client` assembly. It runs fine on Linux except for one specific case, when Xrm.Client wants to create sequential GUID. It relies on DLLImport and calls `UuidCreateSequential` from native Windows's `Rpcrt4.dll`. Of course it crashes on Linux.

The relevant (decompiled) code is:

```
namespace Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client
{
  [SecurityCritical]
  internal static class NativeMethods
  {
    [SecurityCritical]
    [DllImport("Rpcrt4", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern long UuidCreateSequential(ref Guid ptrGuid);
  }
}
```

I do not control this code and i think my options are:

- Use Xrm.Client in a way so it does NOT call `NativeMethods.UuidCreateSequential` (supply GUIDs myself everywhere). The downside is that this is not very convenient for user code.
- Replace `NativeMethods.UuidCreateSequential` at runtime with .NET implementation, eg. using Harmony.
- Create linux library with relevant method so it can be loaded by given DLLImport. I am particularly interested in this option because it looks cleaner than others. However, i'm not sure if this is possible because DLLImport is specified here with `StdCall`. Or maybe it's just because of decompiler.
- Anything else, maybe simpler?

Which solution is better and going to work? How would one approach it?

Answer (score 0):

Time has passed, there are options. The thing is that Microsoft.Xrm.Client is only compatible for .NET Framework

[Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client/) must be used for .NET 6+. One can read more about using this nuget at [Transition apps to Dataverse ServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/sdk-client-transition)

However this package is NOT compatible with on-prem releases as it gives note in the provided link:

> Leave your application projects and code as is. Continue using the Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies NuGet package and CrmServiceClientclass.